# Parents US Tourist Visa Extension more than One Year

Tags: usa, visa, immigration

Thanks for reading my post.

My parents are here in the United States to visit us. They are staying here for more than six months and they are about to leave United States but due to Pandemic they are not able to get the flights and our country is in lock down right now.

They are old and we are afraid them to send immediately.

Is it possible to extend their tourist visa even after one year?

Please share your thoughts on this one.

Comment: What do you mean they "are staying here for more than six months"? B2 visitors are usually admitted for 6 months on their I-94. Have they stayed past the date on their I-94? Have they already applied for Extension of Status once?

Comment: They have been granted one year visa at the port of entry. They are here for almost 10 months

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They can apply for Extension of Status any time before their status expires. There is no limit to the number of consecutive Extensions of Status they can apply for or the total length of stay extensions can add up to.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help